# Seaborn error with kde plot: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data `hue`

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, kernel-density

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with two columns (`type` and `IR`) as this one:

```
   type    IR
0   a      0.1
1   b      0.3
2   b      0.2
3   c      0.8
4   c      0.5
      ...
```

I want to plot three distributions (one for each `type`) with the values of the IR so, I write:

```
sns.displot(df, kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)
```

but I get this error: `The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data 'hue'`

Any idea?

---

EDIT:

My real dataframe looks like

```
pd.DataFrame({"type": ["IR orig", "IR orig", "IR orig", "IR trans", "IR trans", "IR trans", "IR perm", "IR perm", "IR perm", "IR perm", "IR perm"],
              "IR": [1.41, 1.42, 1.32, 0.0, 0.44, 0.0, 1.41, 1.31, 1.41, 1.37, 1.34]
})
```

but with `sns.displot(df, x='IR', kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)` I got `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

Comment: Where is your `x`. Try this: `sns.displot(df1, x='IR', kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'c'}, 
                   'IR': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.8, 4: 0.5}})
print (df)
  type   IR
0    a  0.1
1    b  0.3
2    b  0.2
3    c  0.8
4    c  0.5

sns.displot(df.reset_index(drop=True), x='IR', kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks, but I got `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

Comment: @Palinuro - I add sample data to answer, can you test it?

Comment: Noticeably, the example works with your solution when I run it on ipython but not in my code where I get `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`. I've just edited my question with this.

Comment: @Palinuro  You could try `sns.displot(df.reset_index(), x='IR', kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)`.  Some versions of seaborn/pandas have a problem when the index contains some repeated values.

Comment: @JohanC - Thank you, I use `sns.displot(df.reset_index(drop=True), x='IR', kind="kde", hue='type', rug=True)`

Comment: @jezrael, when I try to adjust my code to your answer I get the exact same error message as before (the one the original poster posted), any idea why?